# Symbol's function definition is void: map

Tags: debugging, emacs

I'm trying to use the following in my `~/.emacs` to require packages that I've installed and would like to use:

```el
(map #'nil (lambda (x) (require x))
 '(
   undo-tree
   savekill
   wrap-region
   free-keys))
```

However, when I try to test it out by having Emacs evaluate the buffer, I get this error: `Symbol's function definition is void: map` I get the same error when I start emacs up normally, I believe that I've fixed this problem before, but I can't remember how I did it.

Here's the debug info that I get when I run: `emacs --debug-init`

```el
Debugger entered--Lisp error: (void-function map)
(map (function nil) (function (lambda (x) (require x))) 
 (quote (undo-tree savekill wrap-region free-keys)))
 eval-buffer(#<buffer  *load*> nil "c:/Users/rr257875/AppData/Roaming/.emacs" nil t)  ; Reading at buffer position 944
load-with-code-conversion("c:/Users/rr257875/AppData/Roaming/.emacs" "c:/Users/rr257875/AppData/Roaming/.emacs" t t)
load("~/.emacs" t t)
#[0 "\205\262
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
map is an alias for `cl-map' in `cl.el'.
```

So first you'll need to:

```
(require 'cl)
```

or alternatively:

```
(require 'cl-lib)
(cl-map ...)
```

Answer (score 4):

As noted in [phils' answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39394982/113848), the reason this isn't working is that this function is from the `cl` library, which implements Common Lisp functions in Emacs Lisp.

There is a "native" Emacs Lisp function that does what you want: `mapc`.  It applies the function on each sequence element, and discards the return value.

```
(mapc #'require
 '(
   undo-tree
   savekill
   wrap-region
   free-keys))
```

(There is also `mapcar`, which is like calling `map` with `'list` as the first argument.)